# What is the purpose of "ifeq (a,$(wildcard .a))" in makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, linux-scst

```
ifeq (.depend_f,$(wildcard .depend_f))
-include .depend_f
endif
```

it is a makefile in [scst fileio](https://github.com/bvanassche/scst/blob/master/usr/fileio/Makefile) , I think maybe just using -include is okay , why we need to use "ifeq (.depend_f,$(wildcard .depend_f))" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you don't need the `ifeq` you can just write:

```
-include $(wildcard .depend_f)
```

We can't really know the reason to do this without seeing the rest of the makefile.  The big reason to do this is that if you write `-include .depend_f` then make will try to rebuild the `.depend_f` file and re-exec itself if it can be updated.  Maybe the author didn't want that to happen.